# How do I use projection to loop without using global variables?

Tags: kdb

There is a wrapper function and would like to use the function to keep deleting but I think only works for a record.

Here are the functions:

```
testFunc1:{
tab:([]a:`1`1`3`1`2;b:2 4 6 8 10);
tab2:update rowNumber:i from tab;
filter:select from tab2 where a = `1;
if [ ((count filter) > 0); tab2:raze .rm.tab[;tab2;filter] each til count filter];
tab:delete rowNumber from tab2;
tab
}

.rm.tab:{[x;tab;filter]
row:exec rowNumber[x] from filter;
if[(count tab) > 0; newTab: delete from tab where i = row];
:newTab
 }
```

The idea is to have `tab` in `testFunc1` and return it as `.rm.tab` is deleting the records one by one. I think there is a bug in `.rm.tab`, if only one record it works fine, but if there are 4 records in filter for looping, the output will return four times.

Not sure how I can fix the `.rm.tab` without using global variables?

Comment: Can you share what you expected the expected output to be from `testFunc1[]`?

Comment: so it will delete all the records that a=`1 from the row Number.  and output the rest. what I think for the solution is  tab2:distinct raze .rm.tab[;tab2;filter] each til count filter] but this is output first then distinct. wondering if there is better solution for looping - store each result for looping

Comment: Is looping necessary? You could just have `.rm.tab[;tab2;filter]til count filter` and then change `if[(count tab)>0;newTab:delete from tab where any i=/:row]` in `.rm.tab`

Comment: Why is it not just as simple as ```delete from tab where a=`1``` ?

Comment: the filter is just an example, it will be compared to something else in my function

Comment: That same filter I'm sure could still be applied to the table directly as a delete statement

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? I've removed the `each` from where `.rm.tab` is called & used `/:` (each-right) inside `.rm.tab`.

**code**

```
testFunc1:{
  tab:([]a:`1`1`3`1`2;b:2 4 6 8 10);
  tab2:update rowNumber:i from tab;
  filter:select from tab2 where a=`1;
  if[(count filter)>0;tab2:.rm.tab[;tab2;filter]til count filter];
  :delete rowNumber from tab2;
 }

.rm.tab:{[x;tab;filter]
  row:exec rowNumber[x]from filter;
  if[(count tab)>0;newTab:delete from tab where any i=/:row];
  :newTab;
 }
```

**result**

```
q)testFunc1[]
a b
----
3 6
2 10
```